# Bash script support piping data into it

Tags: bash, shell, unix, pipe

I have a bash script that I want to expand to support piping json into.

Example:

```
echo '{}' | myscript store
```

So, I tried the following:

```
local value="$1"

if [[ -z "$value" ]]; then
  while read -r piped; do
    value=$piped
  done;
fi
```

Which works in a simple case above, but doing:

```
cat input.json | myscript store
```

Only get's the last line of the file `input.json`, it does not handle every line.

How can I support all cases of piping?

Answer (score 1):

The following works:

```
if [[ -z "$value" && ! -t 0 ]]; then
    while read -r piped; do
      value+=$piped
    done;
fi
```

The trick was using `+=` and also checking `! -t 0` which checks if we are piping.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to behave like `cat`, why not use it?

```
#! /bin/bash
value="$( cat "$@" )"
```

Comment: why `"$@"`?  Isn't `value="$(cat)"` what OP needs?

Comment: With $@, it works both with and without a file name parameter.